# PHP E_STRICT causes blank white screen

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register, spl-autoloader

I am running PHP 5.5.11.  In my php.ini I have

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

My code uses `spl_autoload_register()` to register an autoloader.  When I load a page I get a blank white page.  I get an error in the log that `Foo` can not be found.  Foo is defined in my autoloader.  Here is the basic structure:

`index.inc` calls a method on `A`.  That method calls a method on `B`.  `B` extends `C`.  `C` uses a class constant of `Foo` ( `Foo::LEVEL` ).  It seems that it is the parsing of the class constant that is causing the error.  I can fix this if I go ahead and load Foo at the top of index.inc by calling:

```
$oTrash = new Foo();
```

I can also get rid of the issue by changing my php.ini to:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

The fatal I am getting is not a strict mode error.  I don't understand the impact that E_STRICT is having on the processing of my code.

Comment: Most likely the `E_STRICT` is causing output before headers can be sent which is then causing some other portion of your program to throw a fit. Check your error log (see php.ini for location)

Comment: I have display_errors = Off and my logs are going to syslog but I still don't see any messages.